# gem install mysql2 does not work

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to install mysql2 gem to use in learning rails, but it just doesn't work. Reinstalling mysql or ruby doesn't work. Using ARCHFLAGS doesn't work. I can't use apt-get libmysqlclient-dev because my Mac doesn't have Ubuntu server, and anyways wouldn't this be a dependency included in mysql when installed with homebrew (as I've done)? Also I have the very latest Xcode (8.2.1). This is the complete error message (with username in place of actual user name):

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170121-4906-1lcyftl.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for rb_big_cmp()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/lib
-----
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/mysql2-0.4.5/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/mysql2-0.4.5/gem_make.out
```

The commands I tried to install mysql2 were:

```
gem install mysql2
sudo gem install mysql2 (if the error was permission denied.)
sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17/bin/mysql_config
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'
```

Not sure what exactly those mean, as I did them following advice from similar posts.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the command you use to install `mysql2` and add the full error message? how did you install MySQL itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to alter your environment variables to include the following (just replace the 0.0.00 with the desired version of MySQL2 gem:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.0.00' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

I would also check your `$PATH` and make sure it includes mysql gem, but the above line should work (had a very similar problem)

Comment: T.H.A.N.K Y.O.U! 
This worked after hours of research and dozen other attempted solutions. Now, I hope one day to also learn what it all means :D.